# Cannot change volume with builtin buttons on manjaro anymore

Tags: audio, xfce, manjaro

I installed Manjaro xfce on my Lenovo t430 and it works awesome. I was able to change volume with my volume buttons on the laptop, but after some days it doesn't work anymore.

There is no mechanical fault with the buttons. Please share some commands or config to solve this, as I am a absolute beginner in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall pulse?

```
sudo pacman -R pavucontrol pulseaudio pulseaudio-alsa

reboot

sudo pacman -S pulseaudio
```

Also installing the PulseAudio Volume control software might help?

```
sudo pacman -S pavucontrol
```

Comment: Lol! Very late answer, i already switched to windows.